# Align title and button with that of siblings in CSS

Tags: css

I want to be able to set `min-margin` or something like this in css.

**This is not desired:**
[image]

As you can see, the margin from the picture's title to the buttons is different depends if there is price or not, So not all button are in the same line.

If I put `margin-top` to the **buttons**, or `margin-bottom` to the **title**, it changes the whole set of buttons:
[image]

And **I can't target specific id** since there are a lot of products without price, in each loop it brings four randomly.

So is there any good and short solution for this?

Comment: wrap every image and description in a div (or figure) element with a min-height applied

Answer (score 1):

Just put block wrapper for price (even if there is no price) and set the height for it.

Comment: Or put some "dummy" price (e.g. `<p>foobar</p>`) with `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @Vucko that is sort of dangerous thing in CSS. Never ever do things like that!

Comment: @Trix why is this "dangerous" in CSS?

Comment: @Vucko Good solutions need to have some degree of [extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility) and I think you agree with me on this. Putting an invisible item somewhere to provide the desired visual output, is  not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

You may use flex for child items to have a solid design:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.child{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
.wrapper{
  
}
.button{
  background: #cdcdef;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <P>this is some short text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <P>this is some long very long and even more long text, but this is some long very long and even more long text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <P>this is some short text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <P>this is some short text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Consider having 2 `<p>` elements there. A wrapper would lead to a meaningful solution in this case